# Can 'niggard' be confused with n-word in speech?

Tags: pronunciation

Is the word **niggard** (~ cheap person, miser) popular in speech? My concern is that it can be confused with the derogatory *n-word*, especially when uttered by someone who has an accent.

Comment: I've never heard "niggard" before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_about_the_word_%22niggardly%22

You can form your own opinion on whether it's something worth fighting for being able to use, or if when something this simple that can be solved by saying "stingy" is good enough then you just say "stingy".

The latter is my advice.

Comment: Despite my advice to not choose this particular battle in word use, I will mention that we run a serious risk with technology when rote responses are done to any words.  You never know what's being added in the headers or footers of signatures; and we create profound vulnerabilities to hacking if we give in to it.  **--- This message sponsored by Genuine Viagra Watches Discount Pharmacy Rolex at prices That Would Satisfy The Most Niggardly of Customers**